# Jave - Object in array getting overwritten

Tags: java, arrays, object

Currently I have the following code (class `Car` and a temporary class named `test` to test the former):

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car[][] volvo = new Car[3][3];
        volvo[0][0] = new Car(300, 200);
        volvo[0][1] = new Car(250, 250);

        System.out.println("Car 1 Weight/Height" + volvo[0][0].returnSize() + "/" + volvo[0][0].returnWeight());
        System.out.println("Car 2 Weight/Height" + volvo[0][1].returnSize() + "/" + volvo[0][1].returnWeight());
    }
}

class Car {
    private static int size;
    private static int weight;

    Car(int carSize, int carWeight) {
        size = carSize;
        weight = carWeight;
    }

    public static int returnSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public static int returnWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting from the aforementioned snippet:

```
Car 1 Weight/Height250/250
Car 2 Weight/Height250/250
```

The output I was really hoping to get:

```
Car 1 Weight/Height300/200
Car 2 Weight/Height250/250
```

Is there a reason why the first object being created (`new Car(300, 200)`) is being completely overwritten by the second object, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the fields in `Car` are static. Remove that keyword.

Comment: `private static int size;` <-- `static` is not your friend here

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wonder if there's a proper duplicate for this kind of question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm trying to find me :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer from now on, I'll use that Q/A to close duplicates. Thanks.